# VueJs + Webpack library import in VueJs + Browserify project returns the error : "'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'"

Tags: import, webpack, vue.js, browserify

i have already been through many google pages and still haven't find the answer to my question.
The problem is that i have built a library using Vuejs and Webpack and now i'm trying to use it in a new Vuejs and Browersify project. But when i try to :

```
import Library from 'library';
Vue.use(Library);
```

I get the following error :

```
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

So  i was wondering if such import was possible.
I have already tried all babelify and eslint combinations but here is what i have now in my Browserify project :

```
eslintrc :

// http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  parserOptions: {
    'sourceType': 'module',
    'ecmaVersion': 6,
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
    'es6': true,
  },
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  extends: 'airbnb-base',
  // required to lint *.vue files
  plugins: [
    'html'
  ],
  // add your custom rules here
  'rules': {
    // don't require .vue extension when importing
    'import/extensions': ['error', 'always', {
      'js': 'never',
      'vue': 'never'
    }],
    // allow optionalDependencies
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': ['error', {
      'optionalDependencies': ['test/unit/index.js']
    }],
    // allow debugger during development
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 2 : 0,
    'no-console': 0,
  }
}
```

---

```
babelrc : 

{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
}
```

---

```
package.json :

"watchify": "watchify -vd -p browserify-hmr -e src/main.js -o dist/js/main.js"

"build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production browserify -g envify src/main.js | uglifyjs -c warnings=false -m > dist/js/main.js"

"browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify",
      "vueify"
    ]
  },
```

I tried to import the library in a project that use Webpack and it worked well.

I am becoming kinda desperate so i hope one of you may find the problem and his solution :)

Comment: Might be easiest to just start a brand new project with vue-cli, then copy your `.vue` files over.

Comment: I did initialize both of my projects with vue-cli but you are right i might have messed up too much the configuration files trying to fix things. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: I did try to import my library on a brand new vue-cli browserify project but i still get the same error